# I need to write an excel formula look for a value in a column and set the cell next to it

Tags: excel-formula

I have two sheets in excel
I need to check if the value next to my formula is equal to any of the first sheet first column, If yes I have to write the value next to it (sheet 1, column B, row where the value exists) otherwise I write "Does not exist"

which functions i have to use??

```
"lookup"
```

or

```
"Search"
```

or what ??

thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:A,1,FALSE),"Does not exist")`

Comment: thanks you pointed me to the correct function:
I used =VLOOKUP(A3,Sheet1!$A$2:$H$386741,6,TRUE) Thanks :)

Comment: I could simply use : =IFERROR(LOOKUP(A49,Sheet1!A:A,Sheet1!G:G),"does not exist")

Comment: your formula works as expected with text values, but I found it behaving oddly with numerical-only values (both column and lookup value) that are not found, returning 0.